# ¿How can I locate comments box before the list of comments in Blogger?

Tags: comments, blogger, box

The design of comments of Blogger set the comments box at the end of the comments lists. I think its great, unless there are too many comments. So, I was looking for a way to put the comment box first, I think its better for UX!

Can you help me, please?

PD: I know Google+ comments has this option, but I prefer to keep on my Blogger account! In fact, they (Blogger Help Forum) recomended me with you!

This is what I would like to do:

[image: This is what I would like to do]

Answer (score 1):

Go to **Theme** > **Edit HTML**, search for `<b:includable id='threadedComments' var='post'>` and move the block within `<p class='comment-footer'>` before `<div class='comments-content'>` like the following[image]

Comment: You are welcome, please accept the answer if it is useful to help other users.